# Adding ListView to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I define an XML Layout .At run time I am get LinearLayout from xml Layout file ,I am creating a ListView at run.At run time in ListView I am adding many RelativeLayouts as shown in picture # 5 this RelativeLayout contains different other UI component like TextView,ImageView etc its working fine but when user press back button I am saving ListView object using setter method in beans,When user comes on activity Resume again I am getting ListView from getter method and adding it again to my LinearLayout as I add above but its giving me exception as java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.Before adding ListView after getting again I also try this MyLinearLayout.removeView(myListView)….but problem same . . Any suggestion…[image]

Comment: This sounds very wrong. You're trying to save a list instead the data in it. That could get error prone and could leak memory. I can't see a reason in your question why storing data is not an option...

Comment: @Knickedi I agree with your leak memory problem . .now here is one things I unable to save directly ArrayList to store in SQLite.as its ArrayList is data structure ...so what you suggestion how to process this list? thanks

Comment: Storing array data is most of the time solved with multiple tables and a foreign key relation (there's enough material out there). If your stored array hasn't any relation to other stored elements and you really want to store the array as it is only I would try that by using a text column and a separator between the items (to string when stored, parsed from string on read).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand now, your problem is that when you resume the activity you build a new ListView from code while the app find already this ListView. So, you get an error that you first need the make this ListView empty and then repopulate it with all your data.

The best way to do this:

- Add a ListView in your XML layout
- Get this view in your Activity class with 'findViewById'
- In your on resume() method populate this list with a self created Adapter and data from an ArrayList or Collection
- When you type a new message to send, save it to this ArrayList or Collection and resume your activity or just repopulate your ListView.

But it's maybe better to post some code, so we can better help you.

Kind regards and good luck!